# All Parse Objects Not Presented in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am retrieving objects from a relation in parse. The objects I want are successfully retrieved and printed in the output box, but when I run the app my UITable only presents one of the six objects. Any suggestions on how to get all of them up onto my view? I would greatly appreciate it.

```
 class MyGroupsHomePage: UITableViewController {

let cellidentifer = "MyGroupsCell"


var mygroupsdata: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

func findcurrentuserobjects () {
    var currentuser = PFUser.query()
    currentuser!.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    currentuser!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && object != nil {

            if let object = object as? [PFObject] {

                for objects in object {

                   self.mygroupsdata.addObject(objects)
                }

            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }


}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    findcurrentuserobjects()



}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.mygroupsdata.count
}

var groupnamearray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let mygroupdata: PFObject = self.mygroupsdata.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
    let relation = mygroupdata.relationForKey("UserGroups")
    let query = relation.query()
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objet:[AnyObject]?, erro: NSError?) -> Void in

        if erro == nil && objet != nil {

            if let objet = objet as? [PFObject] {

                for objets in objet {
                    println(objets.objectForKey("GroupName")!)
                    cell.textLabel?.text = objets.objectForKey("GroupName")! as? String

                }

            }

        } else {

            println("Error, could not retrieve user groups \(erro)")

        }



    })


    return cell
}








 }
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to retrieve data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - you should have already retrieved the data.  At the very least you should store the data you do retrieve so that you don't need to fetch it the next time this cell is displayed.  Also which class has 6 objects? the User or the UserGroups?

Comment: Thanks for your advice -the user groups contains the objects - but why is there only 1 object being shown?

Comment: Because you will loop through all 6 objects, but each time through the loop you update the cell text - only the last object's details will be displayed

Answer (score 1):

As [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) stated, this is the problem:

```
for objets in objet {
   println(objets.objectForKey("GroupName")!)
   cell.textLabel?.text = objets.objectForKey("GroupName")! as? String
}
```

You keep updating the same property "text" in the same textLabel, which I assume is an IBOutlet in the UITableViewCell subclass that you use to define the apparence of your cell. Without knowing more of how you want this text to be layed out it it difficult to suggest an answer. A quick and dirty way could be (I haven't tested):

```
for objets in objet {
   println(objets.objectForKey("GroupName")!)
   let obj = objets.objectForKey("GroupName")! as? String
   let newString = "\(obj) "
   cell.textLabel?.text = "\(cell.textLabel?.text)\(newString)"
}
```

But, according to what you want to acheive, you might need to add subviews to your UITableViewCell subclass (either on your cell prototype in Storyboard or programmatically).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What happens when I run your code is that all my objects are printed in one cell

Comment: Yes in one string to be precise. The way your model is structured now, each element of mygroupsdata corresponds to one cell.  tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) is only returning one cell, not multiples.  So you ether change the way your data source is structured or you present the extra object in some detail view.